# Using "on " as a preposition instead of "from"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I read the below text in a book in which the author used the preposition "on" in a new way to mean "from."

she was brutally raped by a physician on the staff of the hospital.

I am familiar with similar prepositional phase, the movie on the watchlist; the killer on the FBI most wanted list, but I still find the above sentence different from these two examples.

Could anyone clarify such usages?

Comment: _On the staff_ is a perfectly normal usage.

Comment: Think of _staff_ as short for _staff list_ or _payroll_ and all looks similar to your examples.

Comment: There are many contexts where prepositions like ***on, from, at, with*** are interchangeable. You can't always assign a very specific "meaning" to prepositions in English, nor can you assume there's only one "correct" preposition for any given context.

Answer (score 1):

It's routine to say "on the staff of X" meaning "one of the people who works for X". I suppose you could say "from the staff of X" and it would mean the same thing but that's not what fluent speakers normally say.

Prepositions are often a bit tricky in that you just have to learn what preposition is used in each context. Sometimes there no obvious general rule. Like we say that you ride "in a car" but "on a plane". Logically it would make more sense to say "in a plane" -- you get inside it; you don't sit on top of it. But that's not what people say.

In this case, we say that someone is "on the staff", not "in the staff" or "from the staff", even though those might sound logical.